# How to get vue to compile template strings with custom components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I now have a string as follows

```
<p><strong>I'm testing the text.</strong></p><p>I'm testing the text.</p><p><CustomComponent v-model='test' />I'm testing the text.<CustomComponent2 v-model='test' /></p>
```

This string was dynamically fetched via a request, and I now want to render the contents and display my custom component, and also generate some data interactions

##### My thoughts are as follows:

Through the plugin to parse this string into ast, and then through the ast and then to determine which is a custom component, write the corresponding component render function generator, and then generate a large render function recursive this ast tree

I don't know how to use the compiler function that comes with vue, but I've been looking for it and it doesn't seem to support runtime compilation. The program is based on client-side rendering rather than server-side rendering

Comment: You can use the vue-template-compiler package with the render function to dynamically compile template strings with custom components in Vue.js. but compiling templates at runtime may have performance consequences.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling#note-on-in-browser-template-compilation

Answer (score 1):

You could implement it like this vue application can be created manually using the createApp and h functions.  :

```
<template>
  <div ref="dynamicComponent"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { transformStyle } from 'vue-template-compiler';

export default {
  mounted() {
    const templateString = `
      <p><strong>I'm testing the text.</strong></p>
      <p>I'm testing the text.</p>
      <p><CustomComponent v-model='test' />I'm testing the text.<CustomComponent2 v-model='test' /></p>
    `;

    // Create a new Vue 3 app
    const app = createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          test: 'some data',
        };
      },
      render() {
        return this.compiledTemplate();
      },
      methods: {
        compiledTemplate() {
          return this.$options.staticRenderFns.reduce(
            (vnode, staticRenderFn) => staticRenderFn.call(this, h),
            h
          );
        },
      },
    });

    // Mount the app to a container
    app.mount();

    // Compile the template string and set it to the app's staticRenderFns
    app.config.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.startsWith('CustomComponent');
    app.config.compilerOptions = {
      nodeTransforms: [transformStyle],
    };

    const { render } = app._createVNode;
    const { staticRenderFns } = app.compile(templateString);
    app._createVNode = render;
    app.$options.staticRenderFns = staticRenderFns;

    // Append the dynamic component to the target element
    app._container = this.$refs.dynamicComponent;
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't seem to be able to use it this way in vue3

Comment: Yes I think, in Vue3 , the structure of the compiled template is different from Vue 2, and there is no components or staticRenderFns method. I edited my answer

Comment: @dincer.unal dude. It's showing `this.$options.compiler` as undefined.

Comment: Thanks @AdityaPrasadDhal, this.$options.compiler is used to access the compiler options, but it's not defined in the Vue 3 instance by default. You can access the compiler options via app.config.compilerOptions instead. Update my answer